# Bad linker in jni

Tags: android, java-native-interface, native

I am doing a native application to Android and I can add native support to my application. But when I want add the Siglib (DSP library wich I use in my c++ code) code:

```
fatal error: siglib.h: No such file or directory
```

My configuration is:

[image]

I think its OK becasu I add the include siglib path.

And my code:

Application.mk

```
APP_STL := gnustl_static
APP_CPPFLAGS := -frtti -fexceptions
APP_STL := stlport_static
APP_ABI := armeabi
APP_PLATFORM := android-8
```

Android.mk

LOCAL_PATH := $(call my-dir)

```
include $(CLEAR_VARS)



LOCAL_SRC_FILES  := nativo.cpp Parameters.cpp
LOCAL_C_INCLUDES += $(LOCAL_PATH)
LOCAL_LDLIBS     += -llog -ldl

LOCAL_MODULE     := native_code

include $(BUILD_SHARED_LIBRARY)
```

nativo.h

```
/* DO NOT EDIT THIS FILE - it is machine generated */
#include <jni.h>
/* Header for class com_sistoleaudiocapture_Processing */

#ifndef _Included_com_sistoleaudiocapture_Processing
#define _Included_com_sistoleaudiocapture_Processing
#ifdef __cplusplus
extern "C" {
#endif
/*
 * Class:     com_sistoleaudiocapture_Processing
 * Method:    init_variables
 * Signature: ()J
 */
JNIEXPORT jlong JNICALL Java_com_sistoleaudiocapture_Processing_init_1variables
  (JNIEnv *, jclass);

/*
 * Class:     com_sistoleaudiocapture_Processing
 * Method:    prueba_nativa
 * Signature: (J)V
 */
JNIEXPORT jdouble JNICALL Java_com_sistoleaudiocapture_Processing_prueba_1nativa
  (JNIEnv *, jclass, jlong);

#ifdef __cplusplus
}
#endif
#endif
```

and nativo.cpp

```
#include "nativo.h"
#include "Parameters.h"
#include <siglib.h>

#include <android/log.h>

#define LOG_TAG "NATIVO"
#define LOGD(...) ((void)__android_log_print(ANDROID_LOG_DEBUG, LOG_TAG, __VA_ARGS__))

JNIEXPORT jlong JNICALL Java_com_sistoleaudiocapture_Processing_init_1variables(
        JNIEnv *, jclass) {

    long dir = (long) new Parameters();

    return (dir);
}

JNIEXPORT jdouble JNICALL Java_com_sistoleaudiocapture_Processing_prueba_1nativa(
        JNIEnv *, jclass, jlong retorno) {
}
```

Help? thanks?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You only told Eclipse where to look for **siglib.h**, please add its path to `LOCAL_C_INCLUDES` in **Android.mk**

Comment: Thaks, the error dissapears, but now when I use a function of this library for example SDA_CorrelateLinear, appears this:
undefined reference to 'SDA_CorrelateLinear'

Comment: Have I to include some else?

Comment: You should start with building the library for Android. As I see on http://www.numerix-dsp.com/siglib.html, this target is not currently supported. I am afraid that the task may not be trivial.

Comment: Ok... do you know some tutorial or something to read about it? thanks so much again!!